# Search computer for .docx, .xls files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and having difficulties trying to locate certain types of files (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx), output the filenames and sizes (in groups by file extension) to a text file, and also include the total number files and total files size for each file extension.

The code that I have so far is:

```
$Report_File_Destination = "C:\Users\StayPositibve\Desktop\testing20.txt"

$path = ".\*"

Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx -Recurse | Group-Object Extension -NoElement | Out-File $Report_File_Destination -Append
```

Every time I run this code, I receive a Get-ChildItem Access is Denied (I am running PowerShell as Administrator). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that it exists some paths that your are not allowed to browse. You can try to use `-ErrorAction Ignore -Force` options of Get-ChildItem to ignore these errors or force access to files that cannot otherwise be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files. in old version of PowerShell you can test `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore -Force
```

Comment: Thank you @JPBlanc for helping out. I tried to add the -ErrorAction Ignore -Force option; however I am still receiving error codes. Another thing that I have noticed is that when use the | Group-Object Extension, it does not copy the found files over to my txt file "testing20.txt" Instead it is blank inside of the txt file. Sorry about not correctly using proper code editing, 1st time using stackoverflow, and do not know how to make the code appear like yours.

Comment: Try -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue if you are using an old version of PowerShell

Comment: The -NoElement explain the fact that you lose your files.

Comment: Thank you so much @JPBlanc for your help. The -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue and your advice about the -NoElement helped out a lot!